# Node JS hangs on Form submission

Tags: node.js

I am just starting node.js and I'm wondering why my small form is stopping when I have submitted the form. This is the code I have:

```
var sys = require('sys'),
    http = require('http');

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            switch (req.url) {
                case '/':
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
                    res.end(
                        '<form action="/myaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
                        '<input type="text" name="field1">' +
                        '<input type="text" name="field2">' +
                        '<input type="submit" value="Submit">' +
                        '</form>'
                    );
                    break;
                case '/myaction':
                    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
                    sys.puts('Hello');
                    /*
                    if (req.method == 'POST') {
                        req.on('data', function(chunk){
                            res.writeHead(200, chunk.toString());
                        });
                    }
                    */
                    break;
            }
    }).listen(8080);

sys.puts('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

As soon as I press submit, the form connects to /myaction but never shows it. I know it connects as I see the 'Hello' text in the terminal. However, I see this on the browser:

> This webpage is not available.
>
> The webpage at
>   http://127.0.0.1:8080/myaction might
>   be temporarily down or it may have
>   moved permanently to a new web
>   address.

Can anyone give light to what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't ending your response correctly on the '/myaction' -case. Use res.end() there also.

Comment: I just got the answer while testing. :)

Comment: Epeli, would you know how to get the data from the form I submitted?

Comment: @Thorpe Obaze from data event.  Example: http://phizcode.blogspot.com/2010/03/beyod-static- nodejs-and-post-method.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you should really use [express](http://expressjs.com/) to help you ease the webdevelopment. Here you can watch a small [screencast](http://screenr.com/6y0) from the creator for a short introduction.

Comment: @Thorpe express/connect is the way too go! Also nodetuts.com has a lot of express.js/connect screencasts which you could watch.